# C++: Vector - Ambiguous overload of "operator -"

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, subtraction, negation

I have ambiguously overloaded the member function `operator-` of my vector (mathematics) class.

Can I resolve this issue? At the moment I am a bit stuck as to how to proceed.

Code:

```
class vector
{
  double mx, my;

  // Constructor not written for clarity

  vector operator-() const;
  friend vector operator-(vector &lhs, vector &rhs);

}

vector vector::operator-() const
{
  return vector(-mx, -my);
}

vector operator-(vector &lhs, vector &rhs) const // Note const here!
{
  return vector(lhs.mx - lhs.my, rhs.mx - rhs.my);
}
```

In case you need to know what the constructor is, it's just the expected:

```
vector::vector(double x, double y)
{
  mx = x; my = y;
}
```

The line of code where the problem flags up is:

```
vector a(0.0, 0.0);
vector b(0.0, 0.0);
vector c = a - b;
```

That should be about enough info to describe the problem in detail. There is also a default copy `operator=`.

The problem is of course that the compiler doesn't know if I want to subtract these vectors or negate one and then get a compiler error due to `vector c = vector vector` or `vector c = a b` if you like, which is nonsense code.

EDIT: I missed a vitally important piece of information, which I now realize explains the problem:

The problematic lines of code appear in a function where the arguments are passed as const references.

```
void function(const vector &a, const vector &b)
{
  vector a(0.0, 0.0);
  vector b(0.0, 0.0);
  vector c = a - b;
}
```

That isn't specifically a problem, however the function I wrote above should have actually been for `operator-=`. The `operator-` (subtraction) is then defined in terms of `operator-=`. So to explain fully, this is the problem:

```
vector& vector::operator-=(const Vector3& rhs)
{
  m_x -= rhs.m_x;
  m_y -= rhs.m_y;
  return *this;
}

vector operator-(vector &lhs, vector &rhs)
{
  lhs -= rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Which explains the problem - the function `operator-` (negation) promises not to modify the members by the use of `const`, and the 2 other operators for subtraction are defined in terms of each other. I think the solution is to do the following:

```
vector operator-(vector &lhs, const vector &rhs)
{
  vector v = lhs;
  v -= rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Or if not that then perhaps the more verbose method:

```
vector operator-(const vector &lhs, const vector &rhs)
{
  vector v = vector(lhs.mx - lhs.my, rhs.mx - rhs.my);
  return v;
}
```

I'll test this now - I've got a bit of a headache at the moment so I guess I must not be thinking 100 % clearly.

Edit: Got it working now, just had to modify the subtraction operator to be a friend function.

Comment: That shouldn't be ambiguous...

Comment: Borgleader is right. Do you got any errors?

Comment: [I can't repro your error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09fca8338384f536) can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Hmm, Okay let me check my code again...

Comment: BTW, missing `const`.

Comment: I have updated my code and will test the proposed changes.

Comment: Not very elegant, but I changed this to a friend function to make it work.

Comment: The binary `operator -` should take its arguments by const reference, not non-const.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes I also made that change

Comment: @Borgleader: it should be `vector operator-(const vector &lhs, const vector &rhs)` (or `vector operator-(vector lhs, const vector &rhs)` according to implementation)

Comment: @Borgleader I've updated that in the code above. Indeed it was defined that way in my original code.

Answer (score 3):

You should define the `operator-` as

```
vector operator-(const vector &lhs, const vector &rhs)
{
    return vector(lhs.mx - lhs.my, rhs.mx - rhs.my);
}
```

The compiler tries to use the unary `operator-` because it applies on a const vector.

When you write `vector c = a - b;` and a and b are const vectors, the compiler looks for the above function which it doesn't find. It only finds an operator with none constant arguments. Since you don't modify the arguments, define them as const.

The `const` keyword you added after it is not valid. It should only appear with methods and specifies that the object is not modified by the method. The compiler should complain about its presence with a function definition.